# Type safety: The expression of type Map.Entry needs unchecked conversion to conform to Map.Entry<String,CredentialParam>

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to Retrieve all parameters stored in the credential object with the following Java code:

`Map.Entry <String,CredentialParam> pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();`

However, I keep getting the following warning:

> Type safety: The expression of type Map.Entry needs unchecked conversion to conform to Map.Entry

Other than suppressing the warning, Is there away I can remove this warning?
Thanks.

Comment: could you add more code including the type of `it`? `Map.Entry` and `Iterator` are generic types.

Comment: Most likely you need to write `Map.Entry<String,CredentialParam>` instead of just `Map.Entry` somewhere in your code.

Comment: @Harmlezz, here the code extract again: 
         Map.Entry <String,CredentialParam> pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();     // I keep getting waning on the right hand side of the code where i have type cast.

Comment: As @domdom mentioned: if `it` is of type `Iterator<Map.Entry<String,CredentialParam>>` then you should declare `pairs` as `Map.Entry<String,CredentialParam>` and remove the casting `(Map.Entry)`.

Comment: @Harmlezz, thanks for your recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that:

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, CredentialParam>> it = map.entrySet().iterator();
```

Do change your code to:

```
Map.Entry<String, CredentialParam> pairs = it.next();
```